# calculating the trajectory of an object in SpriteKit when an impulse is applied to it

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, game-physics

I want to make a trajectory line of little balls of where the object is going to go after an impulse, sort of like what is in Angry Birds. I did some research and it seems that the physics in spriteKit are calculated just as in real life with si units and other stuff. Using the displacement formula ∆x = Vi∆t + 1/2a∆t^2 i used this formula to set the position of nine balls of where the object will be after the impulse.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
func calculateTrajectory(mass: CGFloat, force1: CGFloat, force2: CGFloat){

    for i in 0...8{

        var x = CGFloat()
        var y = CGFloat()

        let a1 = CGFloat(force1/mass)//I am taking the force applied to the object and calculating the acceleration from that 
        let a2 = CGFloat((force1/mass) - 10)//I am subtracting 10 for y because of the -10m/s/s of gravity
        let t = CGFloat((i/16)^2)//I am taking the number that the ball is in the line and dividing it by 16 so the line can show where the object will be from 0-0.5 secnds

        x = 0.5 * a1 * t
        y = 0.5 * a2 * t

        trajectory.copiedNodes[i].position = CGPoint(x:ball.position.x + x, y: ball.position.y + y)

    }



}
```

I also use this in touches moved to do a drag back sling shot sort of thing.

```
calculateTrajectory(mass: (ball.physicsBody?.mass)!, force1: startPositionDrag.x - movedLocation.x, force2: startPositionDrag.y - movedLocation.y)
```

The force for calculation is the same as impulse that I will use to shoot the ball in touches ended:

```
ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx:startPositionDrag.x - endPositionDrag.x, dy:startPositionDrag.y - endPositionDrag.y ))
```

When I calculate this the balls are not close to where the object goes, and when I make the time change for the balls a shorter time amount by dividing i by more, the balls get farther apart even though I am calculating their positions after less time. Is there any way I am doing this wrong? Are my conversions to CGFloat wrong? Please help me.

Comment: I lost the password to that account, so I used another account. Please comment to me and tag me in comments.

Comment: I think your physics is broken. Didn't you used an impulse not a force? Then a term taking in account the initial velocity is missing `vt`

Comment: Is an impulse just applying a velocity? In the documentation it says it is in newtons per second, so wouldn't that be a force? And then it should start out at 0 and then accelerate because of the force... right?

Comment: That worked, but now the line is the right shape, curved with gravity prediction, but the ball doesn't follow the line. It goes partially and then falls back down. It seems like the movement of the ball is being affected by its mass, but the equations say it shouldn't. Do I need to factor the mass into this equation? If so, how?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès do you have any ideas?

Comment: Now you you (usually) do not have to take the mass in account, free fall mecanic is unaffected by mass. If your calculation is parabolic then it is correct, and then some value parameter is probably incorrect. Is there any friction/damper somewhere? Hard to help you more now...

Answer (score 0):

To convert velocities from m/s to pixels per second, you need to multiply sprite kit velocity by 150. Same with acceleration.